# Non blocking queue that allows to poll in batches

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, queue, batch-processing

I have a requirement where millions of records I receive in a stream needs to be stored in database.

I was thinking of using ConcurrentLinkedQueue(CLQ) to put all the data I receive and use a consumer which would poll in batches of 1000 and use batch update to store in DB.
The issue I see using CLQ is that we can’t poll in batches.

I'm not confident of using the drainto method as its not clear whether its safe to use or not.

What options do I have?

Answer (score 1):

Well the javadocs for the `BlockingQueue` state that it is thread-safe.  The javadocs for `drainTo` on `LinkedBlockingQueue` javadoc says this:

> [T]he behavior of this operation is **undefined** if the specified collection is modified while the operation is in progress.

However, that caveat applies to the collection you are draining the to rather than the queue itself.

So, assuming that the `Collection` you are draining to is *thread confined*, it is safe to use `drainTo`.

However ... `drainTo` is a method on `LinkedBlockingQueue` rather than `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`.  And there is a clue in the respective class names.  The `LinkedBlockingQueue` class is NOT a concurrent queue.  Calling `drainTo` will **lock** the queue<sup>1</sup> for the duration of the operation, and that will block any other thread that is attempting to add elements to the queue.  If you are draining up to 1000 elements at a time, the blocking time *could* be significant.

So your choices are:

- Use `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `drainTo` ... if you don't require concurrency; i.e. if blocking of producer threads is OK.
- Use `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` and a loop that calls `poll()` up to 1000 times if you require the queue to be concurrent.

---

<sup>1 - This is what the Java 17 implementation does, and I expect it will be the same for earlier versions.</sup>

Comment: `LinkedTransferQueue` also implements this interface and is not lock based. JCTools also offers its own non-blocking queues with a `drainTo(Consumer<E>)` option which may be a good fit.

Comment: Didn't got with the queue. Used Executors to split the records into batches of 1000 and used jdbc batch update to insert the records.